# Como convertir un string con formato de array a un array

Tags: java, array, matrices, vectores

tengo un ejercicio en java, el cual toma como entrada un string con formato de matriz y se espera como salida una matriz de tipo int.

Me explico, la entrada es un string que tiene el formato de una matriz pero con corchetes, y la salida deberìa ser dicho string convertido a array para poder recorrerlo.
Muchas gracias,
`

```
// Entrada: String array = "[[4,2,4],[8,7,6],[1,3,4]]";
// Salida esperada: {{4,2,4},{8,7,6},{1,3,4}} (de tipo int[][])
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes lograrlo en 3 pasos muy simples:

1. Divide la cadena en filas. En cada fila, asegúrate de eliminar los doble corchetes cuadrados de cada fila.
2. Construye tu matriz de enteros dado el tamaño de las filas y columnas.
3. Separa el string de cada fila por las comas, y parsea la cadena a entero.

Esto en código se puede implementar de la siguiente manera. Te dejo [un demo](https://onlinegdb.com/2rdVjvfMy) que puedes ejecutar online:

```java
public static int[][] stringToMatrix(String s) {
    String[] filas = s.replaceAll("\\s","").split("],\\[");
    for (int i = 0; i < filas.length; i++) {
        filas[i] = filas[i].replaceAll("]]|\\[\\[", "");
    }

    int numberOfColumns = filas[0].split(",").length;

    int[][] matrix = new int[filas.length][numberOfColumns];

    for (int i = 0; i < filas.length; i++) {
        String[] numeros = filas[i].split(",");
        for (int j = 0; j < numeros.length; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(numeros[j]);
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}
```

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias